# MultiPartEntityBuilder server side - java server side (apache tomcat)

Tags: java, android, apache, post, httprequest

I have this client code for `multipartentitybuilder` but I cant find anywhere the server side for processing it.

```
public String multiPartExecute(String url, String keyOfString, String request, String keyForFile, File file)
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart(keyForFile, new FileBody(new File("fileName")));
        multipartEntity.addTextBody(keyOfString, request);
        post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
        HttpResponse response = null;
        String line = "", output = "";

        try
        {
            response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                output += line;
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) 
        {
            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        try
        {
            entity.consumeContent();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        return output;
    }
```

Where can I find information ,or can someone suggest, how to code the server side servlet to parse this post request. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [ServletFileUpload](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html)

Answer (score 0):

use this code for get file from webservice.

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';foreach ($_FILES["photo"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $name = $_FILES["photo"]["name"][$key];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
```

}

Comment: I need a java server side (apache tomcat)

Comment: Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/) tutorial, may be it helps you.

Comment: I am using MultiPartEntityBuilder, so this link unfortunately not helping me, THANKS!

Comment: check [this](http://puspendu.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/restful-webservice-file-upload-with-jersey/)